# Post data via jQuery Issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I don't get response using this code, I'm trying to post and return just a value for testing but I can't fix it:
In php file , I'm just using `<?php return "Post success"; ?>`

Can anyone help me please?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myForm').submit(function() {
    var url = "2534534534534";
    var u_image = "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";    
    $.post('uploadSignature.php',
      {the_image : u_image,the_url : url},
      function(data){
        // show the response
        console.log(data);

      }).fail(function() {

        // just in case posting your form failed
        alert( "Posting failed." );

      });

      // to prevent refreshing the whole page page
      return false;

  });


});
```

Comment: It is no image name, it is image encoded to base64 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By `return "Post success";` you send nothing(content) back. You must change it to:

```
echo "Post success";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, soloution with **echo** is one option. But I prefer return result for AJAX requests as JSON

You can return json for example this way

```
return json_encode(array('status'=>'OK','message'=>'Post success'));
```

And after parse it with

```
  function(data){
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    alert( obj.message );   //return Post success 
  })
```

Reason to use JSON return format, is that, you can simply handle more errors and them reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `<?php return "Post success"; ?>` in the PHP file, simply because return is a keyword that will exit out of a function and can return a value whilst doing that.

The correct way to do what you want to so is `<?php echo "Post success"; ?>` because echo prints it to the DOM(document), you can also use print.

Also just a quick note use single quotations when not using variables in the string for example, `<?php echo "Post success"; ?>` would be less efficient as `<?php echo 'Post success' ?>` because PHP searches for variables in double quotes.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help. :)